# Accessing pytest capsys from inside a test

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have checked the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391770/accessing-fixtures-e-g-capsys-from-a-parametrized-test) and [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039463/how-to-access-the-py-test-capsys-from-inside-a-test) but they don't answer my question.

[Docs1](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#id37) show that you have to send `capsys` as a parameter, as such `def test_output(capsys):` that is also what this other example show [docs2](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html).

However, `None` has a full example that tells me how to access `capsys`

So in my case I have some function

```
 # import a bunch of other modules
 # run a test not calling from terminal

 import pytest 

 def foo():
     print('bar')


 def test_foo(capsys):
     foo()
     captured = capsys.readouterr()
     assert len(captured.out) > 1
```

I know I am missing something simple here, but I have searched around as per the links above and more and have not found any suggestions.

EDIT: The thing is: I do not have access to call `test_foo()` with `capsys`
I don't have the parameter to send it in.

EDIT2: I was able to ran the terminal with `python -m pytest` but still It makes no pythonic sense for me, send a parameter for a function that I don't have... Hence, I cannot test the module myself using

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_foo() 

# This does not work because I don't have `capsys`
```

So, still in need of clarification.

Comment: That looks ok to me - so your assertion fails if the test is run?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I edited the question to make it clearer. I don't have `capsys` to send in as a parameter...

Comment: You mean if you run pytest on that file, the test isn't executed? What is the output of `pytest`?

Comment: I think I understand now what you mean - you think that you somehow have to provide the `capsys` parameter. This is not needed - `capsys` is a fixture provided by pytest, and you just have to run pytest on your test module. You may have to read up on pytest fixtures

Comment: Ìndeed. I ran `python -m pytest` and I got no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how `pytest` tests work.
They cannot be executed directly. Rather, you have to invoke `pytest`, either on the command line, or by calling `pytest.main()` in your code. Both calls work exactly the same, given the same arguments.

Pytest has to do some extensive initialization before running the tests, including loading all fixtures (both build-in, like `capsys`, and self-defined). It then does test discovery in the given module or path (using command line parameters/arguments to filter tests or change the behavior), and executes the tests, using the fixtures given to tests as parameters. There is no way to directly call the test, as the fixtures are not known outside of `pytest`.

To sum it up: `pytest` tests cannot be run directly by calling them, you have to use `pytest` on the command line or `pytest.main()` in a script to do that. For more information, please check the [respective documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html).